# How to test response contains a particular key and value in postman test

Tags: postman

Here I want to validate key and respect value in test like `Name = Test`

```
{
 "Name: Test,
 "Id: 2",
}
```

I have tried:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
pm.test("Name Check", function () { 
    var task = _.find(jsonData, {'Name': "Test"}); 
    pm.expect(task.Name).is.to.equal("Test"); 
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried this but getting Name is undefined                                                                                              var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.test("Name Check", function () {
 var task = _.find(jsonData, {'Name': "Test"});
   pm.expect(task.Name).is.to.equal("Test");
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's the response body, you can just do this:

```
pm.test("Name Check", () => { 
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().Name).to.equal("Test"); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

note your json is invalid because missing the `"` it should be like

```
{
  "Name": "Test",
  "Id": 2
}
```

and you can check it with

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json(); 
pm.test("Name Check", function () { 
    pm.expect(jsonData.Name).is.to.equal("Test"); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pm.test("response has status key", () => {
    let res = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(res).haveOwnProperty('status')
});
```